# Why does subprocess.call(["module","list"]) fail?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm finding the subprocess module wherein you load a list instead of a string (shell=True) to really frustrating. Intuitively, subprocess.call(["module","list"])  should work, but it doesn't and yields this:

```
  File "test.py", line 45, in main
    subprocess.call(["module","list"])
  File "/tools/general/app/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/tools/general/app/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/tools/general/app/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However, `subprocess.call("module list", shell=True)` works. Why?

Comment: perhaps a shell init file does some path manipulations to make it so that `module` can be found?

Comment: Does it work if you use the full path to the `module` program?

Answer (score -1):

This is simply the format of the command. When parsing without going through a shell, it goes through each command and argument individually. But when the interpreter is told to just use the gnome-shell (which is much better at parsing whole command-strings AND is nitpicky about spacing) the format of the command will change to reflect that. This parsing issue is reflected in the security hazard that results from unsanitized input being pumped straight to a shell process. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution. For this reason, the use of `shell=True` is strongly discouraged in cases where the command string is constructed from external input:

Comment: A better selection of the docs would be "If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the shell... On Unix with shell=True, **the shell defaults to /bin/sh**. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell." This might mean that the `module` command is available through the shell, but not when used in Python directly. Since module doesn't seem like a 'real' program, it is unavailable to Python. See Package Initialization in http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/module.html